# Why is there a factor of $\sqrt2$ listed for the neutral pion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, standard-model, normalization, pions

I was reading [the Wikipedia page on pions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion).
At the bottom of the page, there is a listing for the neutral pion ($\frac{\rm u\bar u+d\bar d}{\sqrt{2}}$).

Why are they over the square root of 2?

There is also a note that states

> Make-up inexact due to non-zero quark masses

But no quark has zero mass, right? Does this mean that there is something left over after they annihilate and scientists don't understand why?

Comment: See [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for how to use MathJax (LaTeX) notation to typeset mathematics.

Comment: Have you heard of the term “normalization” for a quantum state?

Comment: Sure, quarks have mass (via the Higgs mechanism), and u & d quark masses aren't identical, which messes with the symmetry of $\rm{u\bar u+d\bar d}$, which would be perfect if they were both massless. (Of course, an antiquark has identical mass to the corresponding quark).

Answer (score 2):

> Why are they over the square root of 2?

This is *supposed to be* the wavefunction of the pion. In order to get a probability of 1 for the modulus square assuming the same masses for the quarks, this is a first order approximation to the real wavefunction.

> Make-up inexact due to non-zero quark masses

This comment is also inexact because not only the masses are non zero at our times, but also there is the strong force binding the quarks which have masses of few MeV with a sea of gluons and quarks and antiquarks which raise the mass of the pion to ~130MeV, by the addition of their [fourvectors.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) Needless to say that the true quantum mechanical wave function will be very complicated, and [lattice QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD) has to be used to model hadrons quantum mechanically. Have a look here to see the complexity of [hadrons](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/)

Comment: why use this for the neutral pion and not the charged ones?

Comment: because the charged one is made up by one quark pair. the square root of one is one. It is not an imposed rule , it is the mathematics of the defintion of the complex conjugate squared of the wavefunction as a probability. Probabilities integrated over all the variables should be 1.

Comment: ahh thanks - you will have to pardon me.. I am not a scientist or a student...  just a 50 year old engineer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. It is related to one half the probability. More accurately when squared, it gives one half.

Say that two states with two different coefficients are $\psi=a|0>+b|1>$. The probability of finding $a$ in state $|0>$ isn't just $a$, but rather the amplitude is needed $a^2$. For your question if $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ that actually just means you have a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance to measure the particle in either state.